# R stars collapse an x/y dimension to a single geometry dimension

Tags: r, geospatial, r-stars

I have a stars object with 2 'raster-like' grid dimensions (but no projection), of x and y. I also have a polygon sf file that contains a field that contains a combination of xy element ids that the polygons correspond to (but will be a subset of them!). I want to reshape the star to remove the xy dimensions and replace with the single geometry dimension. Essentially the equivalent of doing a table join between the data in the star with the xy dimensions.

Here is a reprex:

```r
# create a star
x = seq(1,5,1)
y = seq(1,8,1)
z = seq(1,3,1)
t = seq(1,4,1)

d <- st_dimensions(x=x, y=y,z=z,t=t)

values <- runif(length(x) * length(y) * length(z) * length(t))
data = array(values, dim = c(length(x),
                             length(y),
                             length(z),
                             length(t)))

star <- st_as_stars(data = data,  dimensions = d)
star

# create an arbitrary geometry of a subset of the number of x and y
nc = sf::read_sf(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package = "sf"), "nc.gpkg") |>
  head(0.5 * length(x) * length(y)) |>  # the number of polygons < total number of x * y grid elements
  select(geom) |>
  # add an x-y ID, these are what should be 'joined' with the star xy
   mutate(x = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4), rep(3,4), rep(4,4), rep(5,4)),
         y = rep(c(1,3,5,8),5),
         label = paste0(x,"-",y))
```

I basically need to extract the elements of the star in the nc$label column and make a new star with the geometry of nc applied.

I tried doing something like:

```r
st.g <- star |> filter(x %in% c(1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5),
                       y %in% c(1.5,3.5,5.5,8.5)) 

(nc.geom <- st_set_dimensions(st.g, 1, st_geometry(nc)))
```

but I get an error because the dimensions don't match.

ANy idea how to reduce the xy dimension of the star by matching to the xy data stored in the geometry file?

Comment: This was discussed and answered here: https://github.com/r-spatial/stars/issues/654